# MVC Reducing repetitive code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, razor

I have just started using and am falling in love with MVC design pattern.

My only pet peeve with it is that it seems to produce a lot of repetitive code. For example.

I have a standard MVC App with my DB (models) in one project, separated from my controllers / views / viewmodels in another, again separated from my test methods in another. All working great.

Models:
Now, I have a bunch of nice EF4 classes in my DB project, which I have to use ViewModels for in my real project to access my data. No problem here.

Controllers:
However, every controller I have, essentially does the very same thing. It gets and sets the data from the ViewModels so while each controller is different in that it gets only different data, they are all essentially doing the very same job, in the very same way. (I currently have 9, but this could easily explode to well over 50).

For example:

```
public class Dummy1Controller : Controller
{
    private MyProj.Data.Entities _entities = new Data.Entities();
    private MyProj.Data.Entities2 _coreEntities = new Data.Entities2();

    //GET: /Customers/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (_entities.table1.Count() == 0) return View();

        var pastObj = _entities.table1.First();
        return View(new Table1ViewModel()
        {
            Id = pastObj.Id,
            FirstName = pastObj.FirstName,
            LastName = pastObj.LastName,
            .
            .
            .
            .
        });
    }
}

public class Dummy2Controller : Controller
{
    private MyProj.Data.Entities _entities = new Data.Entities();
    private MyProj.Data.Entities2 _coreEntities = new Data.Entities2();

    //GET: /Vehicles/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (_entities.table2.Count() == 0) return View();

        var pastObj = _entities.table2.First();
        return View(new Table1ViewModel()
        {
            RegNo = pastObj.RegNo,
            Make = pastObj.Make,
            Model = pastObj.Model,
            .
            .
            .
            .
        });
    }
}

public class Dummy3Controller : Controller
{
    private MyProj.Data.Entities _entities = new Data.Entities();
    private MyProj.Data.Entities2 _coreEntities = new Data.Entities2();

    //GET: /Invoices/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (_entities.table3.Count() == 0) return View();

        var pastObj = _entities.table3.First();
        return View(new Table1ViewModel()
        {
            InvNo = pastObj.InvNo,
            Amount = pastObj.Amount,
            Tax = pastObj.Tax,
            .
            .
            .
            .
        });
    }
}
```

Views:
Every view generated from the contollers work great. Execpt, that only thing that changes is the data (fields with labels and text boxes). Once again, they all do the very same job (but with different datasets).

```
@model MyProject.Web.ViewModels.Table1ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CSS/GenericDetailStyles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section id="content">
    <div id="table">
        <div>
            <h2>Customer</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Id)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.FirstName)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.LastName)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)</div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</section>

@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "FooterPartial");}


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


@model MyProject.Web.ViewModels.Table2ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CSS/GenericDetailStyles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section id="content">
    <div id="table">
        <div>
            <h2>Vehicle</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.RegNo)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegNo)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Make)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Make)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.PatientID)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Model)</div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</section>

@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "FooterPartial");}


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


@model MyProject.Web.ViewModels.Table3ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CSS/GenericDetailStyles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section id="content">
    <div id="table">
        <div>
            <h2>Invoice</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.InvNo)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InvNo)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Amount)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Tax)</div>
            <div class="right">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tax)</div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</section>

@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "FooterPartial");}
```

Problem:
I want to make a single controller, and make it dynamic. So that it can read data from different view models. (Why have 9 or 50 controllers esentially doing the same job)

Then I want to do likewise with the views. So that different fields can be dynamically generated. (Why have 9 or 50 views all doing the same job). If the view is based on the controller, the view should be able to change based on its properties.

Essentially all I want to do is find a way to tell the controller to read from viewmodel X or VM - Y or VM - Z ect and it should be able to generate the properties, retreive the associated data, and pass it to the view, which upon receiving, will generate the fields with labels and text boxes.

I guess I want to know if there is any way to do this using reflection. As the view models are basic classes with simple properties. One could potentially create a base controller class that has a method to read in a specified viewmodel object, get its properties, read in also an associated table and match up the fields in that table with the properties in the class. Finally one can pass in the record from the table to display. The view then can be generated automatically based on this using some kind of razor, c# or javascript.

Any taughts on if this is possible or not would be welcome.

Comment: Why do you mix the MVC and MVVM pattern? I guess what I'm asking is, what do you need the ViewModel for and don't just pass the Model?

Comment: @Brunner - Well firstly, its the way I was shown and I dont know how to do it directly (I am relatively new to MVC). Secondly my employeer wants it done this way. Finally, when working on my own projects, I do it this way because I dont like having the actual DB as part of the project like the many examples show, and having it auto generated or regenerated. There are very few practical examples that show you how to connect to a real live database. If you know of any I would really appreicate links to them. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "real live dbs", but you might want to look at POCOs in combination with EF (eg. Code-First) - it is more or less what you have already, just packed neatly. I'm also not sure what you mean by not having the actual DB in the project, given you example you could do "return new View(pastObj);" and you don't even have to edit the View (except the @model declaration though)

Comment: I am using the package manager console to "foreach" through 70 tables making controllers with MvcScaffolding (nuget) using customizable T4 templates for an automatic admin backend and then wiring up custom controllers for any use cases that go beyond CRUD. This way you can go for a walk while your controllers and views are being auto generated.

Comment: @Brunner...I know its late now and I thank you kindly for your input but after almost 2 years experience with MVC I found out the real answer to your question. This is not a mix of the 2 patterns. - On the DB you use EF Models. But between the controllers, and views, you CAN (optional) use another set of models specifically for the views as you may want to restrict access or do some other special stuff. Because of their location and job, effectively models for the view they get their name ViewModels. It has nothing to do with the pattern MVVM, i.e. they are not ViewModels in the MVVM sense.

Comment: @Benjamin - I would really enjoy seeing an example of how you did this. While it would not win you an accepted answer, I would vote your answer and comments up for the favour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)** to remove all the code for copying values between models / entities.

Also, consider using layouts, Data Annotation attributes and templates (with Html.DisplayFor and Html.EditorFor) to shrink your views.

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

You could investigate a possibility of creating a generic base controller class, that will take the type of Model and Entity and will contain common logic for CRUD operations, but it may be a step too far and hinder your development later on.

Comment: @Francis Keep in mind that automapper (or valueinjecter) should be used for one way mapping only, its not recommended to go from a post method back to an entity. It would work in some cases, but falls apart in others dealing with say, the entity framework as properties  don't have their 'modified' flag set, but the object itself does so this results in no changes going back to the db. Just an fyi to anyone else reading.

Comment: @AdamTuliper - I've used AutoMapper with EF without any problems. All AutoMapper does is to call property setters, no different from doing in manually in the code. Could you shed more light on the issues you've experienced?

Comment: I use AutoMapper for 2-way mapping, but I no longer map ViewModels straight back to entities. Our entities now have `protected internal set`ters, to prevent this kind of thing. Instead, I automap from a viewmodel to a command object, then do the actual updating of the entity properties from a command handler. I found that automapping from viewmodels straight to entities was too messy and error prone, with no way to enforce business rules unless they were in the UI layer.

Comment: @danludwig - yes, CQRS is my preferred design pattern now. I'm just surprised that AutoMapper was causing some *technical* problems to EF.

Comment: @danludwig - This seems to add yet another layer to my allready complex structure. I was thinking MVC was just those 3 layers. As I learned more, I started to see a VM being used, and later was reading recommendations on breaking up controllers if they get too complex. If we add additional layers like this as it suits us, are we not better just using a more traditional approach and asking what are the real benifits of MVC when it is actually becomming MVVMC++ with extras. Just something to consider, thanks for your answers.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers - for very simple apps 3 layers will work. For more complex scenarios you need a more resilient architecture that will cope with additional complexity.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers - MVC is just a way to separate concerns in the web UI / presentation layer of your application. Everything in MVC has to do with Web (HTML, JSON, HTTP, etc). In larger projects, your core business layer (domain / entities) is better off when it is free from web concerns.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept your answer. I have been studying it and wanted to be sure it was the right option for me. It is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers - no worries ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I think that one dynamic controller would possibly be a step too far - what happens when you make everything generic and then one of your views requires something more complex than a simple map to the database  - do you extend your 'generic view controller' to deal with this?  Might wind up [here.](http://www.thedailywtf.com)

You should maybe take a look at Automapper to remove some of the repetitive nature of dealing with your viewmodels.

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am taking a look at the automapper at the moment. It might take a few days but will get back after I have done a bit or resarch to choose an accepted answer. In the meantime thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an EditFor/Model templates for object, or ur base class, whatever it is, and then just make one view, which will accept your model, its metadata (with the help of mvc metadataproviders), and build the fields dynamicly according.

[this post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) covers hwo it can be done in mvc2, but u can easily adapt this technique to mvc 3 as well.. 

Im using such a template in a project mi working on, where i have few dozens of different entities, all sharing same look and feel. With the helpe of my own Metadataprovider, which also helps me to get the order of the fields and wheteher they should be visibile in each view, i built one view exactly to show all my entities

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am in the process of reading that link and it seems interesting. Although automapper seems even more so. I can see to some extent why generalising the controller might be a step too far though. But I need to do more research. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: tbh, i never used automapper, and this of course might be the right soltuion for you.. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others here that having one single dynamic controller to handle all models and views in your application is going too far. There are other ways to reduce the amount of code in controllers. Other answers here have mentioned AutoMapper, which is a great tool. The inventor of AutoMapper, Jimmy Bogard, also has a [great video here](http://www.viddler.com/v/b568679c) which includes other things you can do to reduce the amount of code in your controllers.

As far as views, you can already have one view that handles all of your controllers by using EditorTemplates. You can create a customized EditorTemplate that will use reflection to examine the model and render the input fields accordingly. This all uses "model metadata", and there is [a good post on that by Brad Wilson here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking into AutoMapper now because so many people recommended it along with the link to the Brad Wilson site. I will accept an answer in a few days after I have completed my research.